# Allow more then 1 encryption permission itext

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to create a readable pdf that can be open with 2 different password(and is encrypted).
I also want that the pdf have more than 1 permission : printing and screenreadears.

How can I do this? I have tried with :

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,byteArrayOutputStream);
    writer.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.VERSION_1_7);
    writer.setEncryption(firstPass, secondPass, PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_256);
    writer.setEncryption(firstPass, secondPass, PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_256)
```

But obviously it takes only the second permission, so what I have to do?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I don't think the PDF format itself will let you do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this example: https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-12#474-encryptionpdf.java

Specifically this line:

`stamper.setEncryption(USER, OWNER,PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING,PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128 | PdfWriter.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA);`

The permissions are bit flags, so you can logical OR them to add multiple permissions.

Comment: Thank you very much, I used : 
  writer.setEncryption(firstPass, secondPass, PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING | PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_256);
And It works ;)